# INTERMEDIATE MACROECONOMIC THEORY- Fiscal Policy in the Long-Run (Classical) Closed Economy

Tags: fiscal-policy, long-run

Question 2: Fiscal Policy in the Long-Run (Classical) Closed Economy (58 marks)

Consider the following Long-Run Closed Economy Model

Natural Rate of Output: Y = 11,851

Total Demand: YAD = C + I + G

Personal Consumption Expenditures: C = 1,700 + 0.76 (Yd) - 38 r

Gross Investment Expenditures: I = 2,970 - 68 r

Government Expenditures: G = 1,926

Disposable Income, Yd = Y - T
Net Tax Revenue: T = 3,792.32

The Equilibrium of this Economy is characterized by the following data:

Interest: r1 = 8.204

Consumption Expenditures: C1 = 7,512.8448

Gross Investment Expenditures: I1 = 2,412.128

Private-Sector Savings: Sp1 = 545.835

Government Savings: Sg1 = 1,866.32

National Savings: S1 = 2,412.155

Write your answers to three (3) decimal places. Do NOT include the dollar sign or commas separating 000s.

Include the Negative sign when the value of a variable decreases.

SECTION A: Suppose the government raises its spending by $318 million in an expansionary fiscal policy. Calculate the following in your answer booklet and Enter your answers digitally into the online test. (28 marks)

Part 1: Calculate the new equilibrium interest rate after the spending increase:    (6 marks)

Part 2: Calculate the change in Investment expenditures after the spending increase:    (3 marks)

Part 3: Calculate the change in Consumption expenditures after the spending increase:    (3 marks)

Part 4: In the Classical economic model (long-term view of the economy) where output is at the natural rate (YN), the increase in government spending  by $318 million  SELECT ONE  (raises consumption expenditures, reduces consumption expenditures,  leaves consumption expenditures unchanged at)   by SELECT ONE (114, 318, cause no change in consumption expenditures, 204)